# php - Auto close an open html tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've created a blog site where everyone with an account can create his own blog. The new blog post will be saved in a MYSQL database. My problem is that if the user forgot to close an HTML tag, the whole site is displayed wrong.

Example:

```
<p><b>This is Bold</p>
<p>This must be displayed normal</p>
```

How can I fix this with Javascript or PHP?

Comment: regular expressions?

Comment: Add editor in your post something like `CKEditor` or `TinyMC` etc

Comment: Sorry but what you mean?And I dont want to use Editors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I fixed it

```
$content = "<p><b>This is Bold</p>\n<p>This must be displayed normal</p>";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($content);
$content = $doc->saveHTML(); // corrected html
```

Comment: Sorry butafter that he will be displayed`E_WARNING : type 2 -- DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: p and b in Entity`

Comment: I just ran this code and it worked perfectly. Try with this code and then try with your own code. If it doesn't work, show the code where it doesn't work.

Comment: probem in your code is the `<b>` tag is not closed in your old content and it is propagating even to the new content. stop displaying the old content.

Comment: Yes that I see after the Test. Thanks